# Magento is not working after compilation

Tags: magento-1.9, compilation

Initially, observers are not worked & I found that compilation is enabled.So I have used these steps to disable compilation.But no use.After using the third step.The site itself not working.
How to solve this issue?
Thank you in advance!

Steps I have followed:

**`1. Via Magento admin`**

Navigate to System > Tools > Compilation page and click on Disable button
Navigate to System > Cache Management screen and use Flush Cache button.

**`2. Via SFTP, by editing the includes/config.php file`**

To disable compilation in Magento, edit includes/config.php. At around line 28, uncomment the first line and comment out the second:

`#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');`

**`3. Via SSH`**

`php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable
php -f shell/compiler.php -- clear`

Reference links:
[link](http://www.createhosting.co.nz/support/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=49)

Comment: Have you cleared cache and clear session after your compilation process?

Comment: Frontend is loading or giving you any error?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your response.
Both Fronend  & Backend not working after that third step.
I cannot clear cache as the backend is not opening.
I have renamed the var folder

Comment: rename includes directory  to any other name (_includes.unused for example)

Comment: Hai @ChiragRajput no luck even after renaming

Comment: Are you using any other external cache? If yes then please clear it.

Comment: There's no external cache to clear...

Comment: https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-enable-error-messages-in-magento.html - Enable error reporting and see whats error come